# Validating user access logs with pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am not very proficient in pandas, but have been using it for various project for the last year or so - I like it so far, but I have not really gotten a firm grip on it, and so I would love some help. I have tried googling for days, but I'm approaching a point where I just want to use pandas as an iterator, which seems like a waste. I feel I might just be missing some basic terminology and just don't know what to search for, but I am getting fed up with reading and searching.

What I am working on right now requires me to check some logs for valid access, by comparing ID's and dates of access with something like an user registry. I'm using python and pandas because they are the tools I feel most comfortable with, but I am open to suggestions on other approaches. The registry is parsed from a few excelsheets managed by someone else and the logs are nicely ordered csv's.

Loading these into two DataFrames, I want to check each log entry for validity. One dataframe acts as a registry, providing user ID's, a creation date and an end date and the other contains the logs as rows, with userid and a timestamp:

**Registry**

```
                created                 end  ID
1            2018-09-04                 NaT  66f56efc5cc6353ba
2            2018-10-09          2018-11-09  167a2c65133d9f4a3
3            2018-10-09          2018-11-09  f0efc501e52e7b1e1
```

**Logs**

```
                      Timestamp  ID
0       2019-08-01 00:01:48.027  4459eeab695a2
1       2019-08-01 00:06:03.981  e500df5f2c2ed
2       2019-08-01 00:06:36.100  e500df5f2c2ed
```

I want to check each log entry against my registry to see, if access was permitted when it occured. I have written a function to check ID and date against my registry, but I need to figure out how to apply my check to the whole log-dataframe:

```
def validate(userid, date): #eg. 'wayf-1234', datetime.date(2019,11,23)
    df_target=df_registry[df_acl['created'].notnull() & ~(df_registry['end'] < date)]
    return (df_target.values==userid).any()
```

My first inclination was to use the function directly like a row selector (not sure what to call it), but it doesn't work:

```
df_logs[validate(df_logs['id'], df_logs['Timestamp']) == True]
```

I am pretty sure it would be incredibly inefficient to initiate a dataframe for every row to check for a specific date, but I'm just hacking and trying to make something work and inefficient is fine for now. But I would really love know if someone has any input or perspectives on how to work this.
Should I just iterate through the rows of the dataframe and apply my logic for each line (which seems to work counter to how pandas is supposed to be used) or is there a smarter way to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: why not merge on the timestamp and date column (you specify the date part of the Timestamp) as well as the ID ?

Comment: @Datanovice Huh, yea, I suppose I could just merge the two on ID and just validate a single dataframe. That would work I think? Thanks! But I don't see how to merge on timestamp and date, do you mean the created and end columns? If so, they do not match any dates in the Timestamp columns - those timestamps are from actual access for the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge_asof` is the tool here. It allow to exactly merge on a list of columns (with `by`) and then to find the highest value in one column immediately under the value in the other dataframe.

Here you could use:

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(logs, registry, left_on = ['Timestamp'],
          right_on=['created'], by='ID')
```

For each line from logs, you get the line from registry with same ID and a created date immediately below the Timestamp. Then an access is valid if end is NaT or greater that timestamp (after adding one day...):

```
tmp['valid'] = tmp.end.isna()|(tmp.end + pd.Timedelta('1D') > tmp.Timestamp)
```

Beware: this only works if date columns are true pd.Timestamp (dtype datetime64)...